# Initializing two dimensional string dynamic array and passing by reference

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

I am trying to learn C pointer passing. So please forgive my ignorance.

I want to allocate a 2 dimensional dynamically allocated string array in a function.
The function signature is void so the parameters are by reference.

The test file contains these two lines.

```
I am testing.
This is not an empty file.
```

Here is what I have done so far.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_lines(FILE *fp, char** lines, int *num_lines) {
  ssize_t read;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  *num_lines = 0;


  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if (*num_lines == 0) {
      // For the first time it holds only one char pointer
      *lines = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    } else {
      // Every time a line is read, space for next pointer is allocated
      *lines = realloc(*lines, (*num_lines) * sizeof(char *));
    }
    // allocate space where the current line can be stored
    *(lines + (*num_lines)) = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    // Copy data
    strcpy(*(lines + (*num_lines)), line);
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
    printf("%s\n", line);
    (*num_lines)++;
    // After first line subsequent lines get truncated if I free
    // the storage here, then subsequent lines are not read completely
    //if (line) {
    //  free(line);
    //}
  }  
  if (line) {
    free(line);
  }

}
int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char *array;
    int num_lines;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    read_lines(fp, &array, &num_lines);
    printf("After returning\n");
    // Intend to access as array[0], array[1] etc
    // That's not working
    // If I access this way then I get seg violation after first line
    printf("%s\n", &array[0]);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

My questions are inline with code:

- Why can't I free storage for `line` inside the while loop?
- How do I access returned 2D array in `main`? `array[0]` `array[1]` doesn't seem to work? I want to do something similar.
- Why seg fault is generated for the way I am doing it now?

Corrected code will help me understand. Also any good reference anybody can provide to get these concept clarified for C will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `line` is NULL on the first `*line = ...`. Expect problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `free(line)` inside the while loop, you have to reset `line` to `NULL` and `len` to `0`, before the next calling of `getline`. Otherwise, `getline` will think `line` is a valid buffer of size `len`, and may try to write to it, which is actually a so called "dangling pointer" now.

In the `realloc` line, the size should be `(*num_lines + 1) * sizeof(char *)`, one more element need to be allocate to hold the just read line.

And the `array` variable is `char*`, its address is taken and assiged to the parameter `lines` of `read_lines`. So `lines` is the address of `array`, and `*lines` is just `array` itself.

But

```
// allocate `char*[1]`
*lines = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

and

```
// allocate `char*[N]` with N=`*num_lines`
*lines = realloc(*lines, (*num_lines) * sizeof(char *));
```

You assigned a `char*[]` to `array`, which is a `char*` in fact.

So, if you want your function return a array of strings (that is `char*[]` or `char**`) by parameter, you have to make the parameter a pointer to a array of strings (that is `char***`).

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void read_lines(FILE * fp, char*** lines, int* num_lines) {
    ssize_t read;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    size_t buffer_len = 0;
    *num_lines = 0;

    while ((read = getline(&buffer, &buffer_len, fp)) != -1) {
        // `*lines` is actually `array`,
        // modify `*lines` will effectively modify `array`
        if (*num_lines == 0) {
            // `array` now is `char*[1]`
            *lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)); // A
        }
        else {
            // `array` now is `char*[(*num_lines) + 1]`
            *lines = (char**)realloc(*lines, (*num_lines + 1) * sizeof(char*)); // B
        }

        // *(x+n) is the same as x[n], this line is actually doing:
        // `array[*num_lines] = malloc...
        *(*lines + (*num_lines)) = (char*)malloc((read + 1) * sizeof(char)); // C
        strcpy(*(*lines + (*num_lines)), buffer);
        (*num_lines)++;

        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    if (buffer) {
        // `line` is `malloc`ed or `realloc`ed by `getline`,
        // have to be `free`ed
        free(buffer);
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char** array;
    int num_lines;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    read_lines(fp, &array, &num_lines);
    printf("After returning\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_lines; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        free(array[i]); // corresponding to C
    }
    free(array); // corresponding to A or B
    fclose(fp);
}
```